# Clang variadic template specialization error: non-deducible template parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, specialization

I compile following code with clang++-600.0.51:

```
template<typename ... Args> struct seq{};
template<typename Seq, size_t c = 1> struct pop_back;

template<typename ... Args> struct pop_back <seq<Args...>,  0>{
    typedef seq<Args...> type;
};
template<typename ... Args, typename T, size_t c> struct pop_back <seq<Args..., T>,  c>{
    typedef typename pop_back<seq<Args...>, c - 1>::type type;
};
```

and I got an error: class template partial specialization contains template parameters that
      can not be deduced; this partial specialization will never be used [-Werror]

It seems that I specialized the variadic template in a wrong way, <s>but gcc 4.8.2 and vc 2013  can compile it successfully.</s> If I just define pop_back as above, both gcc and vc are passed. all of them are failed if I instantiate pop_back.

Is my code non-standard? how to write a workaround for this?

Comment: hard saying, since we have no idea what `seq` is.

Comment: i missed seq definition. added it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`T` can't be deduced because the compiler can't determine the end of the argument pack `Args...`. You'll need a different implementation. This one concatenates individual elements of the sequence while `c` decreases.

```c++
namespace detail
{
template <typename S1, typename S2>
struct concat_impl;

template <typename... Ts, typename... Us>
struct concat_impl<seq<Ts...>, seq<Us...>>
{
    using type = seq<Ts..., Us...>;
};

template <typename S1, typename S2>
using concat = typename concat_impl<S1, S2>::type;

template <typename Seq, size_t c = 1, typename = void>
struct pop_back;

template <typename T, typename... Args, size_t c>
struct pop_back<seq<T, Args...>,  c, typename std::enable_if<c!=0>::type>
{
    using type = concat<seq<T>, typename pop_back<seq<Args...>, c-1>::type>;
};

template <typename... Args>
struct pop_back<seq<Args...>, 0>
{
    using type = seq<>;
};
} // detail

template <typename Sequence, size_t c>
struct pop_back;

template <typename... Args, size_t c>
struct pop_back<seq<Args...>, c> : detail::pop_back<seq<Args...>, sizeof...(Args) - c>
{ };
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://rextester.com/AJNB49845)

Comment: If someone could suggest a version that doesn't use `enable_if`, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: I must save this question somewhere and raise it as a valid reason for allowing `Args..., T` to be deduced (because seriously, the only reason for this being disallowed is "because it doesn't have [lots of?] use cases and would just increase complexity").

Comment: You are right. I misunderstood the C++ standard. If my understanding is correct, your concat doesn't work as expect, for example, if c is 1 and Seq is Seq<int>. anyway, i catch the point of your solution, and i can finish the rest part of this issue. Great thanks!

Comment: @Griwes, I totally agree with you. i think my thought is nature and it's possible in technical, right? ^_^

Comment: @wingfire Sorry, my previous edit didn't work correctly. It's since been updated to one that works.